# Java Mocktio verify failed at eq(object) even though the objects look the same

Tags: java, mockito

This is the pseudo code,

```
myFunc(class1, class2)
```

in unit test

```
 verify(myService).myFunc(eq(obj1), eq(obj2));
```

But got these outputs:

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
...

Actual invocation has different arguments:
...

I copied the output of obj1 and obj2 to file 1 and file2, "diff file 1 file2" shows no difference.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please can you give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the type of obj1 and obj2 does not have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` function. The responsibility of an `equals` function is to, well, check if two objects are identical in their content. Example:

```
class MyClass {
    public int someValue = 17;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o.getClass() == this.getClass()) {
            MyClass other = (MyClass) o;
            return o.someValue == this.someValue;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my eyes, an error in the equals or hashCode methods is the most likely culprit for OPs problem, thus I do see this as an answer rather than a question for clarification.